# Plugin Architecture with ninject – load class and controller instances from plugin assembly to main MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, ninject

I use this tutorial to create Plugin Architecture in my solution and I also use ninject for the first time:

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=358360&av=526320&msg=4308834#xx4308834xx

Now in MVC application while user is in the process of checkout I get the payment method he selects and need to retrieve the plugin for the selected payment method. I have succeeded in retrieving plugin controller this way, though I have no idea whether it is safe or acceptable practice:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodPluginType);  

 //get plugin controller

var paymentController = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(type) as BasePaymentController;

//get validations from plugin

    var warnings = paymentController.ValidatePaymentForm(form);

        //get payment info from plugin

        var paymentInfo = paymentController.GetPaymentInfo(form);
        //…
```

I also need to access a plugin class for processing the payment.
I have an interface IPaymentMethod

```
  public partial interface IPaymentMethod 
  {
   void  PostProcessPayment (PostProcessPaymentRequest postprocessPaymentRequest);        

  }
```

And plugin PaymentProcessor like this

```
public class PluginPaymentProcessor :IPaymentMethod
    {        
        public void PostProcessPayment (PostProcessPaymentRequest postprocessPaymentRequest)
        {
            ///
        }

Now in MVC project I try to access PostProcessPayment method this way 

IPaymentMethod pluginpaymentmethod = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IPaymentMethod>(paymentMethod.PaymentProcessor);
```

here paymentMethod.PaymentProcessor is “MyApp.Plugins.MyPlugin.PluginPaymentProcessor, MyApp.Plugins.MyPlugin,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null”

```
   And want to use pluginpaymentmethod like i do in controller example

pluginpaymentmethod.PostProcessPayment(postProcessPaymentRequest);
```

but it throws error that resource is not found and pluginpaymentmethod is not loaded. How can I fix it or can you suggest any tutorial with similar implementations? Thank you.

Comment: just a personal opinion but I think you should simplify your process and roll everything back to your basic IPaymentMethod and implement the functionality behind that and then build it up. I looked at the codeproject article and it would appear that someone else had issues using it with ninject, tho the author was succesful with unity. all i'm saying, when it comes to payment gateways etc, you really need to fully understand what's going on and have a robust framework in place. i'm not convinced by this. my opinion only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have a concrete class called `MyPlugin` which has the `IPaymentMethod` interface, then your ninject bindings should look a bit like:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel){
    kernel.Bind<IPaymentMethod>().To<MyPlugin>().InRequestScope();
}
```

check that this is in place in your `NinjectWebCommon.cs` class under the `App_Start` folder. A trickier scenario might be that `IPaymentMethod` has to be registered in the same way that the Ninject `IKernel` is bound:

```
kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
```

that would potentially be a trickier issue to work out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is obvious that i have a very vague idea of the process when it comes to ninject and plugin architecture, but thought it would be rational to have every payment method like this. I'll think of less complicated variant.